# I can't create .war with maven

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I created a .war with maven clean install, now I need create other .war, but I get this error ->

```
- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ tutorial---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\yo\eclipse-workspace\tutorial\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.843 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-24T15:46:51+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/228M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) on project tutorial: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\Users\yo\eclipse-workspace\tutorial\target -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Now My field `\target` is empty and I can't create .war

Comment: Some app seems to be holding a pointer to the target directory. Can you double check?

Comment: one sec, I go restart my pc

Comment: thanks, I restart my pc and I generated .war, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Some other application has opened the target folder. Due to this maven-clean-plugin is not able to delete the target folder and fails.

Comment: how do I identified this ?

Comment: which platform are you facing this issue..windows or linux?

Comment: Windows, I don't found the process in my cmd, I always have restart pc ....